# Android. Перерисовка окна

Tags: android, ui

*Использую следующую структуру xml: 
(Все слои полноэкранные)*

1. RelativeLayout - layout_1 (Visible)
2. CurlView - layout_2 (Visible)
3. RelativeLayout - layout_3 (Visible)
4. CurlView - layout_4 (Visible)
5. RelativeLayout - layout_5 (Visible)

**Алгоритм #1:**

1. Скрываем layout_5, layout_4 => На экране layout_3
2. Ждем действий пользователя.
3. Скрываем layout_3, layout_2 => На экране layout_1.
4. Отображаем layout_5.

**Алгоритм #2:**

1. Скрываем layout_5 => На экране layout_4.
2. Ждем действий пользователя.
3. Отображаем layout_5.

Алгоритм #1 работает без нареканий, в Алгоритме #2 во время выполнения п.3 происходит мерцание в виде кратковременного отображения layout_3 (несколько ms), хотя в остальном тоже все в порядке.

Используемый код для п.3:

```
layout_4.setVisibility(CurlView.INVISIBLE);
layout_5.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
```

Буду рад любой помощи, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Почему вы не используете разные активити для разных слоев? Просто интересно.

Comment: а лучше фрагменты..

Comment: В крайнем случае почему используете Invisible,  а не Gone?

Comment: по мне так лучше активити использовать, так вы запутаетесь просто с нарастанием кода, а между переходами активити можно сделать анимацию нужную, и не заметно будет, что это разные окна :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.
В приложении приходится работать с базой данных, в частности - производить обновление бд, делать это нужно с момента запуска до выхода в отдельном потоке. Причем к этой же бд нужно делать запросы из основного потока. (Сразу вопрос: как это реализовать, ведь встает вопрос быстродействия и одновременного доступа к бд). Эти 5 слоев связаны тем, что используется эффект перелистывания листа бумаги, для этого необходимо, чтобы под CurlPage находился следующий слой. Как реализовать это иначе не представляю. Может, есть идеи? Использую CurlPage by Harism

Comment: Думаю, нужно использовать фрагменты.

Answer (score 1):

[@andgo75](/users/11562/andgo75), в общем, такие советы тебе могу дать. Используй фрагменты для того, чтобы отделить работу отдельных частей от работы Activity, а для того, чтобы выполнять это всё главном UI потоке, использую функцию RunOnUiThread. То, что ты определишь внутри неё, 100% выполнится в главном потоке. Как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!